# Sessão não inicia em php via htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Estou tentando iniciar uma sessão no .htaccess usando `php_value session.auto_start 1` para evitar duplicações de linhas nos códigos php.

Porém isto está a não funcionar, informa que está sempre off?

Answer (score 4):

> Nota: no caso o autor está experimentando a versão gratuita do hostinger, que provavelmente é limitada e não tem suporte completo (não posso afirmar, é uma suposição) e este parece ser o motivo do problema

Acredito que o comando seja `php_flag` e não `php_value`, exemplo:

```apacheconf
php_flag session.auto_start 1
```

Para testar crie um arquivo vazio chamado `teste.php` na mesma pasta que se encontra `.htaccess` com este conteudo:

```php
<?php
var_dump(session_id(), $_SESSION);
```

Deve retornar algo como:

```
string(26) "jgg7lol8o97733q3vgs46tm7p5" array(0) { }
```

Isto significa que está funcionando.

### Solução alternativa

Se acaso isto não funcionar você pode fazer o seguinte, crie um arquivo chamado `global.php`, nele adicione o seguinte conteúdo:

```php
<?php
if (session_id() === '') {
    session_start();
}
```

E inclua este arquivo em todos arquivos necessários, por exemplo o arquivo `index.php`

```php
<?php
require_once 'global.php';
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
Resto do html...
```

Comment: @6paq Sendo um servidor, o motivo deve ser eles que desabilitaram, pois se eu não estiver enganado este modulo consome um pouco mais do servidor, editei a resposta, tente a solução alternativa.

Comment: então creio que este seja o problema, até quantidade de acesso a hostinger limita. vou fazer de forma alternativa e quando contratar o servidor definitivo altero os códigos. obg!